# PHP Require() does not execute required file in the scope of parent script

Tags: php, require, execute

I'm trying to offload the process of connecting to a database to a DBConfig.php file, as suggested pretty much everywhere, because I'll need to reuse the code in several files.

The suggestion is always framed as (edited to reflect my actual code):

```
-------DBConfig.php-------
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
if (!$link) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name');
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db_name : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>

-------Parent.php-------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require_once 'DBConfig.php';
$something = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 30 ");
// This query works fine if the mysql_connect() and
// mysql_select_db() stuff is in this script in place
// of the require_once.
$listofthings = array();
while($temp = mysql_fetch_array($something)){
    $listofthings[] = $temp;
}
// Do other things too
?>
```

But when I try to do `mysql_fetch_array($something)`, it fails with the warning: `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`.

---

Keeping in mind that everything works beautifully if I simply drop the contents of `DBConfig.php` into the parent script instead of `require 'DBConfig.php';`...

And also noting that `print(require 'DBConfig.php'); //- 1` (PHP is returning a 1 to indicate that it is successfully locating and including the file. See [example 5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php))...

What is going on, and how do I fix it? I am using the default configuration for [WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (Apache 2.4.2, PHP 5.4.3), running on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Couple of things quickly: you should use `<?php` tags instead of short tags. And, avoid using `mysql_*` functions because they are being deprecated.

Comment: did you try to include file after mysql_query() function call?

Comment: When no results, `mysql_fetch_array` returns `false`. That might explain the `boolean given` part. Did you check if rows are being returned?

Comment: Also, maybe post your code where you call `mysql_fetch_array()` with the previous line of code too.

Comment: Add this line and tell us the output. if($something){echo "Worked";} else {echo mysql_error();} ...Is your query correct ?

Comment: The query works fine. As I noted below the HR, everything works beautifully if I put the contents of DBConfig.php in place of the `require`.

Comment: I think you need to show your full, actual code, byte by byte. I know your intentions for not doing so are good, but it's probably necessary to recognize the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this

```
require 'DBConfig.php';
```

is *literally* what you are doing, there is absolutely no way the script can be executed in some other scope. If you were using a `http://` URL, it would be the cause but not if you use a relative path like you do.

You are not doing any error checking after connecting to your database, nor after the `mysql_query()` call, so it's more likely it's simply the query breaking. Add proper error checking to your queries and you will know more.

Another possibility is if you call `DBConfig.php` inside a function. Functions will mess with your include's scope. But there's none in your example, so I'm assuming that is not the issue.

Comment: I'll edit the question, because I actually am doing the error checking... I just didn't want to take up even more space than I already was (question's obnoxiously huge to my eyes as it is).

Comment: I should also mention that I believe that the DBConfig code is executed in a different scope because if I add a return to the end of it:

    `return "Hey, I returned something.";`

Then I try to use that value:

    `$retString = require 'DBConfig.php';
    echo $retString; //- 1`

$retString _should_ be the returned value, not 1... so I think PHP is running DBConfig.php and then returning the plaintext response.... and maybe I just answered my own question.

Comment: @jeiquincy if the code above is your actual code, you are not doing proper error checking. Your mysql_query call seems to be failing. Use mysql_error() to see why - that should shed some light on the situation

Comment: The code is failing prior to the query. If I do `require_once 'DBConfig.php'; print($link);` instead of printing a resource number, it throws an error saying $link is undefined.

Comment: @joe ah! Fair enough. That is really, really weird then. I can guarantee you that `<? ?>` blocks do *not* have their own scope.

Comment: ... it works if I omit the closing `?>` from DBConfig.php... I don't even know. But it works now, so I'm going to just call it good at that. Since my rep is too low to answer my own question, I'll flag yours as the answer in the hope that people will read the comments down to this.

Answer (score 0):

Need to know what are you giving in variable $pretend_this_var_is_a_querystring.
This error is usually generated if the query fails. We need to know what string you are passing in mysql_query() function. 
Please do check your query string.

Also in your DBConfig.php. It should be

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $link);
```

Comment: I already stated that the query works fine as long if I type the `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` code in place of `require`.

Comment: Did you try running the query directly in mysql as test query?
Because the error you showed is often generated when query returns false.

Comment: The problem is not the query. The problem is that the code before the query is not executing the way that the documentation is supposed to. If I do `require_once 'DBConfig.php'; print($link);` instead of getting a resource, I get nothing. The problem is BEFORE the query.

Comment: Just for a try. Have you tried using 
    
     include 'DBConfig.php';

Comment: In your DBConfig.php file just add
`<?php
$hostname = "";
$database = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$mb = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>` 
and remove everything else. 
In parent.php file just add
`include 'DBConfig.php';
mysql_select_db($database, $mb);
`
and then your query

Comment: i found the error in your script DBConfig.php.
It should be 
`$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $link);`

Comment: No. As I already told you, it works fine if that exact same code is in the parent script instead of an outside file. Besides, [as documented](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) "If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed."

Answer (score 0):

Probably your query has some mistake. Try
 `mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );`

mysql_query() returns FALSE (boolean) on error.

Comment: "Keeping in mind that everything works beautifully if I simply drop the contents of DBConfig.php into the parent script instead of `require 'DBConfig.php';`..."

Answer (score 0):

If this is exact code that You are using, please change the:

```
require 'DBConfig.php';
```

to:

```
require('DBConfig.php');
```

Comment: Did try this, but it does nothing. Should not matter anyway, as require is a statement, and PHP's allowing coders to format it as a function is only an alias to the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you include the wrong file. (with the same name, but in different location).

If the `DBConfig.php` file that you want is in the same directory of your `Parent.php` try to do

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DBConfig.php';
```

When you include your `DBConfig.php` file, the effect MUST be the same (in your case) if you copy and paste the code of DBConfig in your parent.php file. 
If this not happens, it's because:

- The file that you include is not that you think. (some `set_include_path` in other folder)
- The content of the file that you include is not that you think.

There's no other way.

Comment: Both files are in the same location. That is why there are no slashes in the include string. `require_once 'DBConfig.php';`. Also, the capitalization is correct.

Comment: please... try my solution (add `dirname(__FILE__).`)

Comment: I had tried this previously. You should also note that I mentioned in the OP that `print(require 'DBConfig.php');` was printing a 1, meaning that PHP had found and included a file (and there is no other file with a name even similar to 'DBConfig.php' on my system).

Comment: @joequincy ok. I thought that you have some library with a file called DBConfig.php and the ini_path set for include files from this library. So you include the file with success (printing 1) but it was the wrong file.

Comment: Nope. Default settings from WAMPServer (as noted in the OP). Literally installed and got to work. The project is small... only accessed from the very computer that's hosting it.

Comment: @joequincy I've read your final solution in Pekka's answer. All this has no sense. Believe me :-) So try to understand why all this happens to avoid any other surprise in the future.

Comment: If I had to venture a guess... it'd be that something is misconfigured in the default installation of the WAMPServer package. I've never encountered anything like this before, and unfortunately I know exactly nil about what goes on under the hood in Apache and PHP (a big part of why I don't touch their settings). :/

Comment: @joequincy mmh I don't think is some misconfiguration. The flow is simple: there are 2 files, the first includes the second. It should works. If it does not works then the first file does not includes the second (you got an "undefined var $link" really?). The question is "why"? :-)

Comment: Try to add before your `mysql_query` this line: `print_r(get_included_files()); `

Comment: `Array ( [0] => C:\WAMP\www\index.php [1] => C:\WAMP\www\DBConfig.php )` (and that's after adding the `?>` back in to break it again... following this array is the error output)